# Process builder Limit issue

Tags: apex

I created a process builder which invoke on OpportunitylineItem insertion. Process builder is creating OpportunitylineItem records. This process builder is working fine till i am creating 3 records but when i am trying to crate more than that it throws error on trigger (Too many SOQL). But i am able to insert bulk OpportunitylineItem from UI.

Comment: Is there any trigger/workflow on Opportunitylineitem sObject?

Comment: How many opportunity line items are being created for each Opportunity by the Process Builder?

Comment: If i'm trying to created morethan 4 then i will get error.